# In Pandas, is there an elegant way to assign a category to an item based on whether it contains particular strings?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, categories

I have a .csv file with the following column headers:

Identifier, Date, Task, Category, Person

I want to assign a category or categories to each task, based on whether the task string contains any of a number of substrings, such as:

“met”, “fix, “corresp”, “particip”, “update”, “sent”, “attend”, “help”, “assist”, “research”, “create”, “meet, “send”, “devel”, “source”

I want to write the assigned category(ies) in the ‘Category’ column for each task in each row.

I’ve tried several different approaches. For example, I can get the script to indicate whether a substring exists in the task item and return either a Boolean or binary result:

`df['Task'].str.contains('work', case=False).fillna(0).astype(int)`

or

`df['Task'].str.contains('work', case=False).fillna(0)`

I can also get it to return a list of the tasks that contain a substring:

`df[df > 0]`

But I can’t get the code to write the category into the Category column. I’ve tried every approach I could find, but I think I’m missing something straightforward. I was optimistic about the numpy np.where function, but no dice.

Many thanks in advance for your guidance.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('CAPA Tasks.csv')
df.head()

df['Identifier'].is_unique
df = df.set_index('Identifier')
df.head()

df['Task'] = df['Task'].astype(str)

df['Category'] = np.where(['Task'].str.contains('work', case=False), "Work",
         np.where(['Task'].str.contains('corresp', case=False), "Correspond",
                  np.where(['Task'].str.contains('order', case=False), "Order",
                           np.where(['Task'].str.contains('met with', case=False), "Meet”,

...
                                                                                                                                                      np.where(['Task'].str.contains('receive', case=False), "Administration"))))))))))))))))))))
```

I think I’m failing to convert the task items to strings correctly and am starting to make a mess of my code.

I’ve also tried iterating through each row with if and elseif, but that didn’t work either.

UPDATE: Here’s the functioning code, using the second approach suggested by @mohanys:

`````
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np





df = pd.read_csv('CAPA Tasks.csv')


df['Identifier'].is_unique
df = df.set_index('Identifier')


df['Task'] = df['Task'].astype(str)

df['Category'] = np.select([df['Task'].str.contains('work', case=False), df['Task'].str.contains('corresp', case=False), df['Task'].str.contains('met ', case=False), df['Task'].str.contains('share', case=False), df['Task'].str.contains('made', case=False), df['Task'].str.contains('fix', case=False), df['Task'].str.contains('sent', case=False), df['Task'].str.contains('update', case=False), df['Task'].str.contains('set ', case=False), df['Task'].str.contains('stood up', case=False), df['Task'].str.contains('file', case=False), df['Task'].str.contains('worked with', case=False), df['Task'].str.contains('help', case=False), df['Task'].str.contains('print', case=False), df['Task'].str.contains('develop', case=False), df['Task'].str.contains('partici', case=False), df['Task'].str.contains('attend', case=False), df['Task'].str.contains('talk', case=False), df['Task'].str.contains('plan', case=False), df['Task'].str.contains('order', case=False), df['Task'].str.contains('discuss', case=False), df['Task'].str.contains('taught', case=False), df['Task'].str.contains('teach', case=False), df['Task'].str.contains('writ', case=False), df['Task'].str.contains('research', case=False)],["Develop","Correspond","Meet","Provide","Create","Problem Solve", "Provide", "Maintain & Enhance", "Develop", "Meet", "Administer & Document", "Assist", "Assist", "Produce", "Develop", "Participate", "Meet", "Correspond", "Plan", "Order", "Correspond", "Teach", "Teach", "Write", "Research"])
                          ````
`````

Comment: I think you are already on the right track. If you can you paste snippet of your data & expected output (you can paste them in HTML snippets), it will be much easier to suggest the solution

Comment: Using the second approach suggested by @mohanys, this is working! I’ve added the functioning code above for reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[masked_df,'Category'] == 'whatever_you_want'
```

where masked_df is your boolean result

Comment: Thank you @DerekEden. I feel like this should work, and I’d experimented with masking a little bit. To implement what you’ve suggested, I did the following:

````masked_df = (df['Task'].str.contains('work', case=False).fillna(0).astype(int)) > 0
masked_df['Task'] = df['Task'].astype(str)

masked_df````

but I got a Type Error:
````TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed````

Will keep pushing and see if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

@DerekEden answer

```py
df.loc[masked_df,'Category'] == 'whatever_you_want'
```

is close, but s/==/= to actually change the 'Category' field.

I had a similar issue where I wanted to make a category field based on arbitrary text in a 'summary' field. This is the answer:

```py
df.loc[df['summary'].str.contains('phishing', case=False),'category']='Phishing'
```

Comment: if you have suggestions you can post it on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0):

Using `np.select` looks more organized and readable:

```
cond_list = [df['Task'].str.contains('within', case=False),
             df['Task'].str.contains('corresp', case=False),
             df['Task'].str.contains('order', case=False),
             df['Task'].str.contains('met with', case=False)]
choice_list = ['Work', 'Correspond', 'Order', 'Meet']

df['Category'] = np.select(cond_list, choice_list)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this. you are just missing `df` infront of the column name `Task` (in every instant)

```
df['Category'] = np.where(df['Task'].str.contains('work', case=False), "Work",
     np.where(df['Task'].str.contains('corresp', case=False), "Correspond",
              np.where(df['Task'].str.contains('order', case=False), "Order",
                       np.where(df['Task'].str.contains('met with', case=False), "Meet”,.....
```

you can also use `np.select` instead of `np.where` like below (shown only for 2 items, you can expand it to as many). This might be easier on the eyes

```
df['Category'] = np.select([df['Task'].str.contains('work', case=False), df['Task'].str.contains('corresp', case=False)],["Work","Correspond"])
```

Comment: Will try each of these and report back. :-)

Comment: With the first approach, I’ve been getting this error:

````ValueError: either both or neither of x and y should be given````

The second approach you’ve suggested, however, seems to work! I’m now adding each of the categories using this approach. When I get everything working, I’ll post the final code. Many thanks!

Comment: @DianaAscher the syntax of `np.where` is `np.where(condition, value if condition is true, value if condition is false)`. in the error message you have received, you have missed either of `value if condition is true` or `value if condition is false` for one of the `np.where` (this can easily happen if you have too many nested loops. Try 'np.where` with just a couple of nested loops & check if it works (i am sure it will). Then, you can expand to more nested loops or just use `np.select`. If the code helped you, consider up-voting & accepting it.